# Autocounter in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the following result:

[image]

```js
export const Section = ({ number }) => {
  return <div>Section {number}</div>;
};

export const Container = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Section number={1} />
      <Section number={2} />
      <Section number={3} />
      <Section number={4} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I can't use the code above. The section number should be automatically calculated without passing an argument.

```js
export const Container = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Section />
      <Section />
      <Section />
      <Section />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried to do it through the Context, but because of the React.StrictMode, the counter doubles: 2, 4, 6, 8.

Comment: `The section number should be automatically calculated without passing an argument.` Can you provide more details about that?

Comment: @Edshav I need the section number to be calculated based on external data (like context or global variables), without passing any arguments. The main problem is that I can't pass any arguments to the ```<Section />```. I was able to do it with Context, but the values are doubled due to React.StrictMode :(

Comment: Using `useContext` seems to be the way to go. You would 'register' your section using it and have the context return your current index, which will be stored within a ref in your section. If the parent context value is higher or the same as the one stored, you cancel the registering to avoid doubling.

Comment: Let's solve it together) I created a demo. It seems to work correctly, doesn't it?https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cray-2iuxt7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you just pass the number to Container as a prop? Why can’t you pass props to Section?